# jquery timing with ajax call and html()

Tags: jquery

I am loading a list into a div via perl in an ajax call. 
Once the list is loaded I am triggering a click on the first row:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#newsList').html(data);
  $("#newsList .EDITrow").first().trigger('click');
},
```

But the problem is the timing ... in the code above nothing happens.

html() is a synchronous operation so I guessed that it wasn't loaded in time for the trigger to do it's job.

To test this I wrapped the trigger line in a setTimeout of 1000 it worked fine. ie the first row was clicked and everything associated with the click worked as it should.

As there is not callback for html(), what is the correct way to do this ... clearly the timeout is not the correct way of course.

Comment: Yeah, `.html()` is synchronous, so I would have thought this would work. It would be interesting to see if it still works with a timeout of 1. Maybe that's all it needs.

Comment: use a setTimeout without time like `setTimeout(function(){$("#newsList .EDITrow").first().trigger('click');});`

Comment: I think this is an error in your browser - the `html` call returns before the DOM is properly updated. Could be jQuery as well - but if it works on another browser it would be a browser error. Which browser are you using and have you tried another?

Comment: I've seen this problem few times, it is because of how the dom update happens

Comment: I am using Chrome - just tried Firefox and the same problem there too ... and yes, amazingly a timeout of just 1 works too.  So is this the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

try using `$("#newsList .EDITrow").delay(1000).first().trigger('click');`

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, a timeout of just 1 millisecond does the trick